# How to align specific element to the right using :last-child pseudo

Tags: html, css

At this fiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/jeljeljel/sARz2/

I need to align the bolded date values to the right of the parent container.  Using a :last-child pseudo element how would I adjust the css to make this happen?  I have an attempt at this in the css below.

**HTML**

```
<div class="editIssueForm">
    <div class="commentContainer">
        <div>
            <div class="comment">
                <div>
                    <span>Entered by: Paul Reid</span>
                    <span>4/3/2013 3:45 PM CST</span>
                </div>
                <div>ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent pulvinar, lectus vitae rutrum accumsan, ligula mauris bibendum magna, vel vestibulum erat ante vel metus. Integer blandit, libero eu dignissim pellentesque, massa lectus placerat mi, eu adipiscing neque velit vitae turpis. Maecenas iaculis dui in urna iaculis mattis. Suspendisse ut erat turpis. Nullam pulvinar fringilla semper. Nulla facilisi. Nunc eu tortor eu ipsum adipiscing facilisis. Proin lacinia quam non nulla fermentum a cursus nunc consequat. Suspendisse id diam orci, sed pretium nibh. Sed eros tortor</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.editIssueForm {
  border: 1px solid lightblue;
  width: 300;
}
.editIssueForm .commentContainer {
  width: 300;
  height: 200;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.editIssueForm .commentContainer .comment {
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.editIssueForm .commentContainer .comment div:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**these pseudo selectors don't work. how can the css be adjusted to make them work?**

```
.editIssueForm .commentContainer .comment div:first-child span:first-child {
  float: left;
  padding-left: -5px;
}
.editIssueForm .commentContainer .comment div:first-child span:last-child {
  float: right;
}
```

**end**

```
.editIssueForm .commentContainer .comment div:first-child:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.editIssueForm .commentContainer .comment:nth-child(n+2) {
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your span is correctly floated right, the problem is just the wrapper `div` of your `span`. Try to add:

```
.editIssueForm .commentContainer .comment div:first-child {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sARz2/6/)**

Answer (score 2):

Your selectors are actually working fine ..

You need to give the containing `<div>` a width of 100% so that the second `<span>` can float to the right edge of the main container, instead of being constrained by its parents width (due to the nature of inline-block elements when no width is specified)

http://jsfiddle.net/Adrift/mFBfB/

---

<sup>Note that the margin doesn't collapse like it does in @Niels answer, because margins never collapse on floated elements, even with its in-flow block-level descendants</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `inline-block` on the direct parent, it shrinks the element to its contents, nullifying the float settings.

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/uZu6f/1/